# Prevent losing graphs when using Spreadsheet::ParseExcel

Tags: perl, spreadsheet, cpan, activeperl, parseexcel

I need to edit the data and graphs of an excel file. I can edit the data but graphs are lost.

[Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.59/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm) says:

> You can only rewrite the features that Spreadsheet::WriteExcel supports so macros, graphs and some other features in the original Excel file will be lost. Also, formulas aren't rewritten, only the result of a formula is written.

Is there any workaround for this?